# Ant copy task: include extra lines up to the closing ";"?

Tags: ant

I have an (see below) Ant copy task which successfully copies all lines that contain the 5 elements within the regexp pattern but these statements which end in ";" sometimes go over one line but these extra lines are not included.  Is their a way to included these extra lines up to the closing ";"?

```
<copy file="${updates-dir}/updates.sql"
      tofile="${updates-dir}/updates_filtered.sql">
  <filterchain>
    <linecontainsregexp>
      <regexp pattern="BEGIN;|INSERT INTO|UPDATE|DELETE FROM|COMMIT;"/>
    </linecontainsregexp>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Comment: Can you also post an example of the sql file to show what exactly you want Ant to do and and what the problem is?

Comment: Was my answer any use John?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing arbitrary SQL using regular expressions is *hard*.  In Ant it's no different, but, if your input is consistent enough you may be able to get away with it.

One option may be to process the input by SQL statement - i.e. split it on semicolons rather than line endings - using a [tokenfilter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#tokenfilter).  A variation on what you have posted might therefore be

```
<filterchain>
  <tokenfilter>
    <stringtokenizer delims=";"/>
    <containsregex pattern="BEGIN|INSERT INTO|UPDATE|DELETE FROM|COMMIT" />
  </tokenfilter>
</filterchain>
```

You can optionally exclude the delimiters from the output.

If your input is not 'clean' it will be difficult to robustly cater for all input possibilities with a simple filter like this.